(although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factor -
Service Class:
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.FieldValueList;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.QueryJobConfiguration;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.TableResult;

private ItemCurResponseDTO validateItemFromItemCur(Integer itemNbr,StringBuilder errorString,MutableBoolean hasErrorOccured)
    {
        TableResult results;
        List<ItemCurResponseDTO> itemCurResponse = new ArrayList<>();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        String query = "SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(result) from (select item_nbr,dept_nbr from wmt-edw-prod.US_WC_VM.ITEM_CUR where item_nbr =" + itemNbr + ") as result";
        QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query).build();
        try
        {
            //Need to mock this line
            results = bigQueryService.executeQuery(queryConfig);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ie)
        {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            throw new BigQueryException(ie.getMessage());
        }

        for (FieldValueList row : results.iterateAll())
        {
            try
            {
    //In this line ObjetMapper didn't work          itemCurResponse.add(mapper.readValue(row.get(0).getValue().toString(), ItemCurResponseDTO.class));
            } catch (JsonProcessingException jpe)
            {
                log.error("JsonProcessingException converting ItemCur Data to ItemCurResponseDTO Object {}", jpe.getMessage());
            }
        }

        if(itemCurResponse.isEmpty())
        {
            errorString.append("Invalid item number|");
            hasErrorOccured.setTrue();
        }

        return itemCurResponse.size()==0?null:itemCurResponse.get(0);
    }

DTO:
@Data
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
public class ItemCurResponseDTO {

    @JsonAlias({"ITEM_NBR"})
    private Integer itemNbr;

    @JsonAlias({"DEPT_NBR"})
    private Integer deptNbr;

    @JsonCreator
    public ItemCurResponseDTO (@JsonProperty("ITEM_NBR") Integer itemNbr,@JsonProperty("DEPT_NBR") Integer deptNbr ) {
        this.itemNbr = itemNbr;
        this.deptNbr = deptNbr;
    }
}

//Testing
//SaveRollOut Test Data
static  Schema SCHEMA = Schema.of(
        Field.of("ITEM_NBR", StandardSQLTypeName.INT64),
        Field.of("DEPT_NBR", StandardSQLTypeName.INT64));

static FieldValueList newFieldValueList() {
    return FieldValueList.of(ImmutableList.of(
            FieldValue.of(FieldValue.Attribute.PRIMITIVE, 10101),
            FieldValue.of(FieldValue.Attribute.PRIMITIVE, 1818))
    );
}

private static final Page<FieldValueList> INNER_PAGE_0 = new PageImpl<>(
        new PageImpl.NextPageFetcher<FieldValueList>() {
            @Override
            public Page<FieldValueList> getNextPage() {
                return null;
            }
        },
        null,
        ImmutableList.of(newFieldValueList()));

public static TableResult ITEM_CUR_VAL = new TableResult(SCHEMA, 1, INNER_PAGE_0);

When I'm running this test case
@Test
public void invalidInput3Test() throws Exception {
    try {
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(rolloutPlanService, "triggerSource", "GCP");
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(rolloutPlanService, "defaultEnv", "testEnv");
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(rolloutPlanService, "defaultToken", "testToken");
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(rolloutPlanService, "defaultURL", "testURL");
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(rolloutPlanService, "rolloutJobName", "testJobName");


        Mockito.when(bigQueryService.executeQuery(any(QueryJobConfiguration.class))).thenReturn(ITEM_CUR_VAL);

        Context context = Context.of(RollOutSolutionOperation.SAVE_ROLLOUT);
        String tenantId = ConstantsUtil.tenantIdValueUS;
        ServiceRequest < RolloutInfoDTO > rolloutInfoDTO = new ServiceRequest < > (RolloutInfoUtil.inputWithMandatoryFieldsPresentMinMaxWkValidation1());

        Map < String, Object > map = new HashMap < > ();
        map.put("tenantId", tenantId);
        map.put("rolloutId", 8 l);
        map.put("rolloutInfoDTO", rolloutInfoDTO);
        ServiceRequest < Map < String, Object >> serviceRequest = new ServiceRequest < Map < String, Object >> ();
        serviceRequest.setPayload(map);

        context.put(BaseKeys.UPDATE_ROLL_OUT, serviceRequest);

        rolloutPlanService.updateRollout(context);

    } catch (AllocationRuntimeException allocationRuntimeException) {
        Assert.assertEquals("Field values can not be negative|Invalid Min week|Invalid Max week|Commit Qty should be multiple of Pallet Qty", allocationRuntimeException.getError().getMessage());
    }

}

Im getting this error:
ERROR com.walmart.sams.services.allocation.configuration.service.RolloutPlanService:319 - JsonProcessingException converting ItemCur Data to ItemCurResponseDTO Object Cannot construct instance of com.walmart.sams.services.allocation.configuration.dto.response.ItemCurResponseDTO (although at least one Creator exists): no int/Int-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from Number value (10101)
at [Source: (String)"10101"; line: 1, column: 1]
